# Interface cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I have gotten myself into an interesting situation, and i am confused since i think i am doing all the right stuff here... I am getting the following error:

```
The current type, Services.Interfaces.IKenticoService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, Services.Interfaces.IKenticoService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Source Error:


Line 113:            throw new InvalidOperationException("Container on Global Application Class is Null. Cannot perform BuildUp.");
Line 114:
Line 115:        container.BuildUp(this as T);
Line 116:    }
Line 117:


Source File: c:\PROJECTS\CMS\CurentSprint\currentsprint\Source\WebProject\App_Code\Global\BasePage.cs    Line: 115
```

and the error is generated by base page:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        InjectDependencies();

        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }


/// <summary>
    /// This method is used to inject any controller related dependencies from
    /// our existing web page.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void InjectDependencies()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context == null)
            return;

        IContainerAccessor accessor = context.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;

        if (accessor == null)
            return;

        IUnityContainer container = accessor.Container;

        if (container == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Container on Global Application Class is Null. Cannot perform BuildUp.");

        container.BuildUp(this as T);
    }
```

I have the mappings in place:

```
namespace Core.DI
{
    public static class UnityHelper
    {
        public static void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {

            container.RegisterType<IPersonRegistrationService, PersonRegistrationService>();
            container.RegisterType<ILoginService, LoginService>();

            container.RegisterType<IKenticoCMSOfferService, KenticoCMSOfferService>();
            container.RegisterType<IKenticoService, KenticoService>();

            and then i have some other...
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called in side global Application Start method:

```
public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Azure Application start init
        AzureInit.Current.ApplicationStartInit();

        CMSAppBase.CMSApplicationStart();

        //CustomCode: Added for DI (Unity block)
        try
        {
            //CustomCode: Create the unity container.
            Container = new UnityContainer();
            UnityHelper.ConfigureContainer(Container);

            //mappings
            EntityMapper.MapEntities();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: add call to error logger.
        }
    }
```

My KenticoService class is setup properly as well:

```
namespace BusinessLogic.Services
{
    public class KenticoService : IKenticoService
    {


        #region User API Calls


        public void HandleCmsUser(Person person, string userName)
        {
            ...
        }


        public void HandleCmsUser(Person person, string userName, string oldUserName)
        {
            ...
        }

        #endregion




    }
}
```

Now the kentico service methods are called inside LoginService and PersonRegistrationService only. So in both the classes i have:

```
[Dependency]
        public IKenticoService KenticoServiceInstance { get; set; }
```

Now we have two sites, our custom MVC solution and a CMS site. The services referenced above are in the projects that are inside our MVC solution. For CMS use, we copy the dlls over to the CMS solution. The MVC solution compiles and runs great. The CMS site is throwing this error and i have double checked that the correct dlls are being referenced here. Are you seeing something here that i may be missing?

Comment: What is `T` on this line: `container.BuildUp(this as T);`? Is this generic type an interface?

Comment: Yes. There are other service interfaces and I have followed the same rule, the way those are setup. None of the others throws this exception. The only difference here is that this service is getting called from 3 other services, which means that it is not being utilized directly from any asp.net page or controller.

Comment: It is not a DI issue here. I removed DI registration code for the service having problem. Moved the methods to another service and utilized from there. IKenticoSrvice and KenticoService, interface and class were just simply sitting in the their respective projects and i still got the same error. I deleted the interface and issue is no more. I am total clueless as to why this interface alone had an issue.